# How can I add a redirect for after my webpage is liked?

Tags: redirect, facebook-like, response.redirect

I have a https website with a facebook like button on it. I'm already tracking events and integrating them into google analytics. I would like to be able to add a redirect as well once someone clicks on the like button and posts to facebook. My facebook button is set up with the following:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the facebook like button code is as follows:

```
<fb:like style="float: left; margin: 1px 10px 0 0;" href="<?php echo $share_url;?>" send="false" layout="box_count" width="65" show_faces="false" font="verdana"></fb:like>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'Facebook', 'Like', href]);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social Shares', 'Facebook Like', href]);});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget) { _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'Facebook', 'Unike', href]); });
</script>`
```

Is there anyway I can add a redirect to this and still be able to track clicks with google analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after plucking away at this for a while now and much frustration I was able to get a solution that worked. I ended up creating my own app and using the direct url feed dialog method

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

to create a dialog app and added an onClick event for GA tracking and redirecting. In the end my facebook buttons link looks something like

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=000000000000000<?php echo "&link=".urlencode($share_url)."&picture=".urlencode($image)."&name=".urlencode($title)."&caption=&description=".urlencode($description)."&redirect_uri=".urlencode("$redirect").""?>" style="float: left; margin: 66px 10px 0 0;" onclick="trackPost(); window.location(this.href); return false;">Post This</a>`

Wasn't exactly what I had originally planned on and this is not using "Likes", but instead "Posts" or "Shares". However, it does work great. I would like to thank Marcelo for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Just add window.location = 'URL YOU WANT' after your GA code in the subscribe callback.

Example:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
   _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'Facebook', 'Like', href]);
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social Shares', 'Facebook Like', href]);
   window.location = 'URL HERE';
});
```

Sorry about that, I assumed that the callback was after completion.

---

Much more complicated but working solution:

The regular 'like' button does not have a callback function for when the person actually finishes in the dialog box.  Luckily you can create a custom dialog using [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/).  You will have to create a FB app for your domain.

I modified and tested their example code to use a redirect instead of an alert box.

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>

<a id="link" href="#">Post to Feed</a>

<script>
FB.init({appId: "000000000000000", status: true, cookie: true}); //You'll need to insert your appId.

$('#link').click(function(){
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
        description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
    },
    function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
          window.location = "http://www.google.com"
      } else {
          // Do something else here if they do not post.
      }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I gave this a shot and it actually posts to facebook like this but believe it or not it does not do a redirect. Very strange.

Comment: I copied and pasted the revision code that Marcelo gave, obviously replaced 'URL HERE' and still not getting a redirect. I'm completely lost on this. Is it because it is https:? Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: If i use the FB.ui can i still add my edge events to track in google analytics with the response to redirect?